# fwrite not return 0 when harddisk is full in linux why?

Tags: c, linux, memory, memory-management, fwrite

when hard disk is 100% full, fwrite(say 1000 Bytes)  return 0 [Fail , as expected]
but when hard disk is  has little empty space say 600Bytes , then fwrite (1000 bytes) not 
return 0 [fail] but return say 300 Bytes , again calling fwrite still return 300bytes, fwrite never fails , even if we call 100 times ?

The Error no is setting properly to 28. My question is Why is behaviour of fwrite ? is this right? if fwrite return less than bytes which we want to write then this means disk is full ?

anh suggestion to handle this situation ?

Comment: `fwrite` is buffered.  Nothing hits disk until `fflush` or `fclose`.  One of those will fail.

Comment: +1 @William Pursell, 300*100 bytes is less than 30kB and the buffer can easily be bigger than that.  At the last point where need to know if an error will occur you need to flush the buffer explicitly.  Normally use waiting till `fclose` is good enough, but sometimes you need to `fflush`.

Comment: Extending my comment: an `fwrite` may trigger a `write` as well as `fflush` or `fclose`, but that is usually a rare event.  This is why it is important to check that `fclose` succeeds!

Comment: Thanks For response : My doubt is why calling fwrtie next time not failed[return zero] ? Always return same short byetes [less than actual bytes for write]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

POSIX says this about [`fwrite`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fwrite.html):

> If an error occurs, the resulting value of the file-position indicator for the stream is unspecified.

This means that repeating that same `fwrite` on the same stream is an error in your code - you don't know where the stream is positioned, so attempting to write to it is not a good idea at all.

You handle this like it seems you're doing already: check `errno` after a short `fwrite` and do whatever is appropriate for your application.

Comment: Thanks For response : My doubt is why calling fwrtie next time not failed[return zero] ? Always return same short byetes [less than actual bytes for write

Comment: You cannot know what the stream state is after a failure. It can be imagined that the stream position was not advanced in that case and stayed where it was. But you cannot rely on that _at all_. It's not guaranteed by anything. The second write you emitted would be a bug in your code, essentially.

Comment: Hi , To check the error , we have to use errno or ferror() ? which work in all OS ?

Comment: Refer to the documentation of the platform you're working on. If it's POSIX compliant, then the link above tells you what happens if there's an error: "Otherwise, if a write error occurs, the error indicator for the stream shall be set,  and errno shall be set to indicate the error." - so both ferror and errno will have information. If you're not on a POSIX system, you need to look up the documentation for that system to see what you need to do.

Answer (score 3):

From the [fwrite man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fwrite):

> On success, `fread()` and `fwrite()` return the number of items read or written. This number equals the number of bytes transferred only when size is 1. **If an error occurs, or the end of the file is reached, the return value is a short item count (or zero).**

So, a short write is an indication of an error, and `errno` should be consulted to see why the write did not complete. After consulting `errno`, Mat`s answer explains (and the C Standard says basically the same thing, except it uses the term *indeterminate*), the file position is invalid after an error, so trying to continue to use it after failure is not well defined.

Comment: Thanks For response : My doubt is why calling fwrtie next time not failed[return zero] ? Always return same short byetes [less than actual bytes for write]

Comment: As Mat explained, and I reiterated, the second call to `fwrite()` results in undefined behavior.

Comment: Hi , To check the error , we have to use errno or ferror() ? which work in all OS ?

Comment: Every stream has an error indicator, but the C Standard only specifies that it indicates whether an error has occurred (true or false). The `errno` is the only way specified by the C Standard to retrieve a reason for failure. But, a short return value by `fwrite()` is already an indication of an error, so calling `ferror()` again would be superfluous.